# How to append certain items to a new list if a specific index is empty

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of vendors and their emails. The emails are in their own list because some vendors have more than one point of contact. However some vendors haven't responded with a email contact so that field for that item is empty. It looks like this:

```
list1 = [['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com']]
['Company Name', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']]
['Company Name', []]
['Company Name', []]]
```

I already have an email filter function which detects the items that have no email and pops them:

```
for k in range(len(list1) -1, 0, -1):
    if not list1[k][1]:
        list1.pop(k)
    return list1
```

However I want to copy those items to a new list for a reporter tool before I remove them. So I tried this but flagged always =[] when it shouldn't.

```
flagged=[]
for k in range(len(list1) -1, 0, -1):
    if not list1[k][1]:
        flagged.append(k)
        list1.pop(k)
    print(flagged)
    return list1
```

My desired results would be having all the items that had no emails copied to the flagged list.

Comment: I would suggest switching to a dictionary data type for this, key would be the company name and value would be the list of provided emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what output you're going for, but this will return a list of company names with no emails

```py
company_contacts = {'Company A': ['email1@companyA.com'],
                   'Company B': ['email1@companyB.com', 'email2@companyB.com'],
                   'Company C': []}

missing_emails = [company for company, emails in company_contacts.items() if not emails]
```

Output:

```py
['Company C']
```

Using a list input:

```py
company_contacts = [['Company A', ['companyemail@email.com']],
['Company B', ['companyemail@email.com','companyemail@email.com']],
['Company C', []]]

missing_emails = [contact[0] for contact in company_contacts if not contact[1]]
```

Output:

```py
['Company C']
```

If you want to remove, I'd do it without popping but create two lists: one that's the list of company with contacts (in essence pop) and one that's the list without contacts.

```py
company_with_contacts = []
company_without_contacts = []
[company_without_contacts.append(contact[0]) if not contact[1] else company_with_contacts.append(contact) for contact in company_contacts]
```

Output:

```py
company_without_contacts = ['Company C']
company_with_contacts = [['Company A', ['companyemail@email.com']],
 ['Company B', ['companyemail@email.com', 'companyemail@email.com']]]
```

Comment: Is that company_contacts a list?

Comment: `company_contacts` is a dictionary, `missing_emails` is a list

Comment: Is there a way to do this with company_contacts as a list?

Comment: Added that solution

Comment: Thank you. And one last question. Does this remove those items from company_contacts or is it just copied to flagged?

Comment: Updated to have them removed

Answer (score 1):

```
company_details = [
    ['Company Name A',['Company Email A']],
    ['Company Name B',['Company Email B']],
    ['Company Name C',['Company Email C']],
    ['Company Name D',[]],
    ['Company Name E',[]]
]
```

**Using List Comprehension**

```
no_emails = [company[0] for company in company_details if not company[1]]

print(no_emails)
```

Output

```
['Company Name D', 'Company Name E']
```

**Using Function**

```
def companies_without_emails(company_details):
    '''
    This will return a list of companies
    without emails
    '''
    names = list()

    for company in company_details:
        if not company[1]:
            names.append(company[0])
    return names

print(companies_without_emails(company_details))
```

Output:

```
['Company Name D', 'Company Name E']
```

**Using Inline Lambda Functions**

We could remove companies without emails using this.

```
company_details = list(filter(lambda x: x[1],company_details))

print(company_details)
```

Output:

```
[['Company Name A', ['Company Email A']], ['Company Name B', ['Company Email B']], ['Company Name C', ['Company Email C']]]
```